# $\sup$ of a set of functions

Tags: integration, supremum-and-infimum

For $\alpha>0$, let $\mathcal{S}_{\alpha}$ be the set of functions $f:[-\alpha,\alpha]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ with the property $\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}(f(x))^2\mathrm dx=1$.

What is the $\sup$ of the set $\left(\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}f(x)\mathrm dx\right)^2+\left(\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}xf(x)\mathrm dx\right)^2+\left(\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}x^2f(x)\mathrm dx\right)^2$ for $f\in\mathcal{S}_{\alpha}$.

I first prove that

$$
\left( \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} \sqrt{x^2+1}|f(x)|\ \text{d}x \right)^2
\geq
\left( \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} f(x)\ \text{d}x\right)^2
+ \left( \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} xf(x)\ \text{d}x \right)^2
$$

and

$$
\left( \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} \sqrt{x^2+x^2+1}|f(x)|\ \text{d}x \right)^2
\geq
\left( \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} f(x)\ \text{d}x\right)^2
+ \left( \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} xf(x)\ \text{d}x \right)^2+
\left( \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} x^2f(x)\ \text{d}x \right)^2
$$
I am wondering if I can use Cauchy-Schwart at this stage.

Comment: You are using nonstandard notation in the second line.

Comment: Where does this problem come from ?

Comment: Consider the functions $$f_\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases}0& x \le \alpha - \epsilon\\\sqrt{\frac 1 \epsilon}&x > \alpha - \epsilon\end{cases}$$